# unsaved value in Nhibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate, orm

What is the need for unsaved-value attribute?? is it true it doesnt exists in Nhibernate 3.2?

```
<id name="ID" column="ID" unsaved-value="0">
<generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsaved value is used by Nhibernate to determine if it need to insert value or update.